# Condtionally hide Edit action for resource in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Is there any way to conditionally hide the 'Edit' link per row on #index of a resource?

For example, say you have a `User` resource. While a User is active, you can edit the User. However, once the User deactivates their account, it should no longer be editable. The User should still show up on the index page with the View link still.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make your column instead of default_actions column:

```
index do
  column :actions do |resource|
    links = link_to I18n.t('active_admin.view'), resource_path(resource)
    if resource.is_active?
      links += link_to I18n.t('active_admin.edit'), edit_resource_path(resource)
    end
    links
  end
end
```

Comment: Syntax is a little different but you da real mvp